# Let $T \in L(V)$ and $f(x) \in F[x]$. Prove that $η(f(T)) = η(d(T))$, where $d(x)=$gcd$(f(x),m_T(x))$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T \in L(V)$ and $f(x)$ be an arbitrary polynomial in $F[x]$. Prove that $η(f(T)) = η(d(T))$, where $d(x)$ is the greatest common divisor of $f(x)$ and the minimal polynomial $m_T(x)$. $η(f(T))$ denotes the null space of $f(T)$.

**My attempt**: Since $d(x)$ is the gcd of $f(x)$ and $m_T(x)$, there exist $p(x),q(x) \in F[x]$ such that $d(x)=p(x)f(x)+q(x)m_T(x)$. Which implies $d(T)=p(T)f(T)$ as $m_T(T) = 0$. So for all $v \in η(f(T)) $ , $d(T)(v)=p(T)f(T)(v) \implies d(T)(v)=0$. Hence $v \in  η(d(T))$. This proves that $η(f(T)) \subseteq η(d(T))$.

The above method cannot be used to show $η(d(T)) \subseteq η(f(T)) $. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* To prove that $η(d(T)) \subseteq η(f(T)) $, write $f(x)=g(x)d(x)$.